# Cuba-Platform ReactUI - FileUpload

Tags: reactjs, cuba-platform

I'm fairly new to both React and Cuba in general.
I can't seem to get the FileUpload-Component from [@cuba-platform/react-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cuba-platform/react-ui) working. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

I always get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFileUploadURL' of undefined
    at FileUploadComponent.render (index.esm.js:362)
    at allowStateChanges (mobx.module.js:1146)
    at index.module.js:951
    at trackDerivedFunction (mobx.module.js:896)
    at Reaction.track (mobx.module.js:2082)
    at FileUploadComponent.reactiveRender [as render] (index.module.js:945)
    at FileUploadComponent.makeComponentReactive (index.module.js:1015)
    at FileUploadComponent.target.render (index.module.js:1196)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:18484)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:18439)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:20176)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:337)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:386)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:439)
    at beginWork$$1 (react-dom.development.js:25777)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:24694)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:24667)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:24256)
    at react-dom.development.js:12286
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:704)
    at runWithPriority$2 (react-dom.development.js:12232)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:12281)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:12269)
    at batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:24377)
    at reactionScheduler (mobx.module.js:2223)
    at runReactions (mobx.module.js:2191)
    at endBatch (mobx.module.js:1826)
    at _endAction (mobx.module.js:1129)
    at executeAction (mobx.module.js:1076)
    at res (mobx.module.js:1060)
```

Any working example of how to use the component, would be marvelous.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: For clarification, I'm just using the FileUpload component like this: `<FileUpload />`

That's all I'm doing, but I'm having the feeling that I'm missing something essential here. Docs don't really help me either, as I'm fairly new to React as previously mentioned.

Also, I can't find any working sample on the internet which might show me how to use the component, so I'm quite lost on this matter. As mentioned, any working example using the FileUpload component would be a huge help!

Thanks!

Comment: You should provide additional code, like any JSX used to build this and any other related stuff that could help in debugging. Providing the error without additional context is not that helpful.

Comment: @Pipetus I edited it, I hope that clarifies it a bit

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [CubaApp](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/frontend/cuba-frontend-docs/v20.1/api-reference/cuba-rest-js/classes/_cuba_.cubaapp.html) hasn't been initialized.

Have you created your app from scratch or have you generated it using [front generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cuba-platform/front-generator)?

If the former, then you need to wrap your component tree in [CubaAppProvider](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/frontend/cuba-frontend-docs/v20.1/cuba-react-core/cuba-app-provider.html). You can see a working example in a [generated starter app](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/frontend/cuba-frontend-docs/v20.1/client-react/starter-guide.html).

If this happens in a generated app, then could you please post a minimal reproduction  repo somewhere?